# Get Permisson of your App Using Appium and Webdriverio aka wdio without using adb

Tags: automation, webdriver, appium, adb, webdriver-io

Recently I ran into a problem of getting granted Permissions of my app using Webdriver IO and Appium. I found a solution hope this will help people. Please find the solution below :

```
const get_permissons = await browser.execute(
'mobile: getPermissions',
{appPackage:"com.package.name",type:"granted"}
);
console.log(`Get Permissons ${get_permissons}`);
```

References :

Link 1 : https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/

Link 2 : https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver#platform-specific-extensions

Answer (score 0):

```
const get_permissons = await browser.execute(
'mobile: getPermissions',
{appPackage:"com.package.name",type:"granted"}
);
console.log(`Get Permissons ${get_permissons}`);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.